# Grafana continuously reports 401 errors attempting to access the endpoint /api/ws/live

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, grafana, monitoring, amazon-eks

We are running Grafana on EKS Kubernetes v1.21 as a Helm deployment behind a Traefik reverse proxy.

Grafana version: `v9.0.3`

Recently, Grafana has been posting this same log message every minute without fail:

```
2022-08-24 15:52:47 
logger=context traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000 userId=0 orgId=0 uname= t=2022-08-24T13:52:47.293094029Z level=info msg="Request Completed" method=GET path=/api/live/ws status=401 remote_addr=10.1.3.153 time_ms=4 duration=4.609805ms size=27 referer= traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000
2022-08-24 15:52:47 
logger=context traceID=00000000000000000000000000000000 t=2022-08-24T13:52:47.290478899Z level=error msg="Failed to look up user based on cookie" error="user token not found"
```

I can't confirm whether these two log messages are related but I believe they are.

I cannot find any user with id `0`.

Another log error I see occasionally is

```
2022-08-24 15:43:43 
logger=ngalert t=2022-08-24T13:43:43.020553296Z level=error msg="unable to fetch orgIds" msg="context canceled"
```

What I can see, is that the `remote_addr` refers to the node in our cluster that Grafana is deployed on.

Can anyone explain why this is continually hitting the endpoint shown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Grafana Live feature is real-time messaging that uses websockets. It is used in Grafana for notifying on events like someone else is editing the same dashboard as you. It can also be used for streaming data directly to Grafana. [Docs here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/set-up-grafana-live/)

You can either turn off Grafana Live or configure your proxy to allow websockets.

- [Turn it off by setting config option `max_connections` to zero](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#max_connections)
- [Instructions on how to configure the Traefik proxy with Grafana](https://grafana.com/tutorials/run-grafana-behind-a-proxy/)
- [Setup guide for Grafana Live](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/set-up-grafana-live/#configure-grafana-live)